# How to make application dynamic. (adding online database) xamarin.android

Tags: c#, database, listview, xamarin

I created an application about guide for hikers for our research study. with list view in it, Im using custom adapter and pass data from array. I created it by searching examples and tutorials in youtube. Our app is working fine but our adviser is not satisfied. He requires us to put online database so we can update the contents of our application without change the codes in order for us to pass, he wants us to create a database and implement into our app and whenever we update the database, the content in our application should be updated. I do not know where to start. As I've search in the internet for some useful examples I cannot see one. please help. any suggestions would be appriciated. thank you :)

Comment: Xamarin's site has numerous examples of apps that work with remote data sources

Comment: I personally am a huge fan of using Azure to host a Web API and sending HTTP requests from the app to said API. This prevents the app from communicating directly with the database, so your DB auth info doesn't live in the app. I would give Entity Framework a look also, it's a great ORM and I use it for all my .NET stuff.

Comment: hello sir can you provide some useful links for it? was reading about azure